# Provide content for a div with different ID name

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, clone

I am trying to create a website with an add button that allows the client to duplicate the form. While doing that, I am losing the hide/show option functionality that is existing due to the duplication. ( `ifYes` and `ifNo` divs, one should show based on customer selection)

My issue lies in the variable 'Valu' in my JavaScript or so I assume.

Below is a snippet of my code:

HTML:

```
<select id="ValuType" name="ValuType" onchange="priceAndCheck()">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Type of Property</option>
    <option id="Apartment" value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
    <option id="Building" value="Building">Building</option>
    <option id="Farm" value="Farm">Farm</option>
    <option id="House" value="House">House</option>
    <option id="Land" value="Land">Land</option>
</select>


<div id="ifYes" class="ifYes">
...ifYes content comes here...
</div>

<div id="ifNo" class="ifNo">
...ifNo content comes here...
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function yesnoCheck() {

    var Valu = document.getElementById("ValuType").value;

    if (Valu == 'Apartment' || Valu == 'Farm' || Valu == 'Land') {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.height = '250px';
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.transition = 'all 1s ease 0.59s';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.height = '0px';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.overflow = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.transition = '0.55s';
    }
    else if (Valu == 'Building' || Valu == 'House') {
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.height = '250px';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.transition = 'all 1s ease 0.59s';
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.height = '0px';
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.overflow = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.transition = '0.55s';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.overflow = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }
}



function providePrice() {

var a = document.getElementById("Region").value;
var b = document.getElementById("ValuReq").value;
var c = document.getElementById("ValuType").value;
var d = document.getElementById("Express").value;
var e = 25;




if (a=="Region1" && b=="Bank" && c=="Apartment" && d=="Yes")
{
    var x = 200 + e;
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Price: OMR " + x;

}

else if (a=="Region1" && b=="Bank" && c=="Apartment" && d=="No")
{
    var x = 200;
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Price: OMR " + x;
}

else if (a=="Region1" && b=="Bank" && c=="Building" && d=="Yes")
{
    var x = 350 + e;
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Price: OMR " + x;
}
...
...
...
else
{
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = "Price:"
}


    function getValue() {
if (document.getElementById("Express").checked) {
    document.getElementById("Express").value = "Yes";
 } else {
    document.getElementById("Express").value = "No";
 }
}


function priceAndCheck(){
    yesnoCheck();
    providePrice();
}
```

**Code Explanation:**
Whenever a client fills the form and and selects certain options, it should allow the div `ifYes` or `ifNo` to show up and price to be populated. (Price connected to more than one field, ) I am doing this using the `div` names and it works perfectly. However, when cloning the form I am not able to generate the divs `ifYes` and `ifNo` for all the new cloned forms.

Where I believe the issues lie in are in the following:

- my `div` namings are constant (exactly the same in all cloned forms) which is one of the problems
- Calling `priceAndCheck()` function that calls two functions `yesnoCheck()` and `providePrice()` that makes me need to change all functions if I start calling an element (E.g. `function test(selectElement)` -- Tried [Sam Apostel's solution][1] and was unable to view the options as required with all my available coding.
- The `div` that is cloned has a different `id` name but all the other `divs` within have the same naming

Would be grateful for some help on what is the optimum way to deal with this issue.

Comment: where and when do you call `function yesnoCheck()` ?

Comment: @irshadjm Sorry, forgot I call two functions when I change the option. onchange="priceAndCheck()" has the function yesnoCheck() in it.

Comment: you are facing issues because once your form is duplicated you will lose the functionality of getting object using id as now you have multiple elements with same id, WHICH ISN'T ALLOWED, In this case you will always get reference of last element if your try to access it by ID,  I would suggest you to update your logic to get element by class.

Comment: @amitwadhwani when I use the above code, only the first element has the functionality. I changed all elements to receive by ClassName but it didn't work. I may have missed out on something but I think my issue would be that I need to change the naming of IDs and class names, correct?

Comment: Rather than relying on the DOM, could you keep a list of these elements in an array (/dictionary, with the ID as the key) or something (growing the array when you create and add the element to the DOM)?

Comment: @ataulm would honestly need to understand the difference between DOM and pure JS first to be able to do that. Will look into it and check if it would make my life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple testings and code edits, I came up with the below solution to my query where I utilize the class name for each cloned form, options become viewable, as required.

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
  
  var Valu ='';
  var count = 0;
 
  $('.ValuType').each(function() {
   
   Valu = $(this).attr('id');
   Valu = document.getElementById(Valu).value;
   
   

      if (Valu == 'Apartment' || Valu == 'Farm' || Valu == 'Land') {
    document.getElementsByClassName('Yes')[count].style.height = '30px';
          document.getElementsByClassName('Yes')[count].style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementsByClassName('Yes')[count].style.transition = 'all 1s ease 0.59s';
    document.getElementsByClassName('No')[count].style.height = '0px';
    document.getElementsByClassName('No')[count].style.overflow = 'hidden';
    document.getElementsByClassName('No')[count].style.transition = '0.55s';
      }
   else if (Valu == 'Building' || Valu == 'House') {
    document.getElementsByClassName('No')[count].style.height = '30px';
    document.getElementsByClassName('No')[count].style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementsByClassName('No')[count].style.transition = 'all 1s ease 0.59s';
    document.getElementsByClassName('Yes')[count].style.height = '0px';
    document.getElementsByClassName('Yes')[count].style.overflow = 'hidden';
    document.getElementsByClassName('Yes')[count].style.transition = '0.55s';
   }
      else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('Yes')[count].style.overflow = 'hidden';
    document.getElementsByClassName('No')[count].style.overflow = 'hidden';
   }
   
   
   count++;
  });

 }
  
  
  
  //define template
var template = $('#content:first').clone();


//define counter
var count = 0;

//add new section
$('body').on('click', '#repeat', function() {

 var clone = template.clone();
    //increment
    count++;
 
 //remove cross button div
 clone.find('cross').removeAttr("#cross");
 
 //update id of ifYes & ifNo
 clone.find('.Yes').prop('id', 'ifYes' + count);
 clone.find('.No').prop('id', 'ifNo' + count);
 
    //loop through each input
    var inputSection = clone.find(':input').each(function(){

        //set id to store the updated section number
        var newId = this.id + count;

        //update id
        this.id = newId;

    }).end()
 
    //inject new section with animation
    .appendTo('#content').hide()
 .appendTo('#content').slideDown(500)
    return false;
});

//remove section
$('#content').on('click', '.cross', function() {
    //slide up section
    $(this).parent().slideUp(500, function(){
        //remove parent element (main section)
        $(this).parent().child().empty();
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

```css
.Yes{
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 0;
     -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease;
     -o-transition: all 1.5s ease;
     transition: all 1.5s ease;
}


.No{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <button type="button" id="cross" class="buttonImgTop cross">remove</button>
   <div id="ValuWrapper">
   
   <select id="ValuType" name="ValuType" class="ValuType" onchange="yesnoCheck()">
 <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Type of Property</option>
 <option id="Apartment" value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
 <option id="Building" value="Building">Building</option>
 <option id="Farm" value="Farm">Farm</option>
 <option id="House" value="House">House</option>
 <option id="Land" value="Land">Land</option>
   </select>
                   
      <div id="ifYes" class="Yes"> 'Yes' class text comes here </div>
      <div id="ifNo" class="No">  'No' class text comes here </div>
   </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="buttonImg" id="repeat">repeat</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your question (using `this` in the `onchange=""`tag)

```js
$ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).style;
}
function priceAndCheck(selectElement){

yesnoCheck(selectElement);
}
function yesnoCheck(selectElement) {
  var show;
  var hide;
  var Valu = selectElement.value;
  if (Valu == 'Apartment' || Valu == 'Farm' || Valu == 'Land') {
    show = $('ifYes');
    hide = $('ifNo');
  } else if (Valu == 'Building' || Valu == 'House') {
    show = $('ifNo');
    hide = $('ifYes');
  }
  show.height = '250px';
  show.display = 'block';
  show.transition = 'all 1s ease 0.59s';
  hide.height = '0px';
  hide.overflow = 'hidden';
  hide.transition = '0.55s';
}
```

```html
<select id="form1" name="ValuType" onchange="priceAndCheck(this)">
    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Type of Property</option>
    <option id="Apartment" value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
    <option id="Building" value="Building">Building</option>
    <option id="Farm" value="Farm">Farm</option>
    <option id="House" value="House">House</option>
    <option id="Land" value="Land">Land</option>
</select>


<div id="ifYes" class="ifYes">
  ...if Yes content comes here...
</div>

<div id="ifNo" class="ifNo">
  ...if No content comes here...
</div>
```

Comment: Unable to get it to work with my code as I have 2 functions running at the same time when the option is changed. Can I not just add the `this.id` in the function I am calling? As in:
priceAndCheck() {
yesnoCheck(this.id);
function2();
}

Comment: I changed my answer to accommodate a nested function and changed `this.id` into `this` so that you don't have to look into the DOM to find the ellement

Comment: Still doesn't work. It seems if I call two functions I cannot use this method unless I change my 2nd function as well, or so I assume.

Comment: Added more code and explanation, hope that provides more clarification on my code.